# Logging and tracing on mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know what are my options for logging and tracing in mvc4, in my old days I used to use external frameworks, I remember I used log4net many times and also the enterprise library.

I am looking an easy way that I can enable/disable logging and tracing to improve performance. So I would enable logging/tracing  only when an unknown exception is occuring.

As I come from the Sharepoint world, there, you can configure different logging levels, verbose, monitorable, high, exceptions, etc.

I wonder if I can do the same with asp.net mvc.

Comment: [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) still does the job fine.

Comment: I am looking for the most popular one for mvc, it looks like Elmah is the most downloaded one.

Comment: You should use Elmah + NLog. Elmah is for unhandled exceptions, while nLog is a 'generic' logger. Those two can work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use log4net without problems.

We use a different logger, [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), which definitely works with ASP.NET. It has specific examples for ASP.NET

Here's a [blog entry about using NLog with ASP.Net](http://rickyrosario.com/blog/asp-net-logging-using-nlog/).